# On click url prompt open with using app Html web page

Tags: javascript, html

When i am using a href link with rtsp on a web page and when i click on a mobile browser it ask for open with app.
I want to implement same thing for a http url to choose open with app.
How can i achieve it.

Comment: rtsp is a specific protocol that is handled in a specific way. If you want links to trigger the opening of an app that is most likely done within the app itself and registering it with the OS to be opened when specific domains are visited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use app scheme in your Android app.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data>
        android:scheme="app"
        android:host="yourAppName
    </data>
</intent-filter>
```

Then you can use the link app://yourAppName

Comment: I am not having an android app this is a web page which is PWA app. Can you tell me how to achive it in a web page